# Move_base action doesn't come up while Sending Goals to the Navigation Stack!

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!
I'm trying to use the code that sends goals to the navigation stack from this Link:
https://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals, while using Turtlebot3 simuliation, but without any success! i only get this response: Waiting for the move_base action to come up. I tried changing the move_base action name to move_base_simple but still nothing!
the thing is it worked as i tried it with a real Turtlebot3. I would be so grateful for any suggestion.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399462/move_base-action-doesn%27t-come-up-while-sending-goals-to-the-navigation-stack!/) by [Belghiti](https://answers.ros.org/users/99615/belghiti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2022-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi again!

It was just a very NOOB mistake on my part, I didn't start the navigation stack, I started SLAM and wondered why it is not working!! in the end everything just fell into place.

---

Originally posted by [Belghiti](https://answers.ros.org/users/99615/belghiti/) with karma: 50 on 2022-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1